# Why aren't the subheads linkable on the FAQ pages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

On the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, I was trying to link a user to the paragraph with the heading: *Help Others Reproduce the Problem*.  However, it seems that I cannot link to a subhead because there is no anchor or id attribute on them.

Do you think adding this functionality to the FAQ would be a good feature?

Comment: I think linking with a head is always helpful to reference a link but a user should read everything at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  page.So I don't think we need link to subhead at that page

Comment: Agreed. In this case, as the user has a relatively high rep, I don't suspect him to have not read the FAQ but I would like to point him to the right place to correct the issues with the way he asked his question.

Comment: Link and quote the relevant parts?

Answer (score 1):

They're not linkable because, as far as I can tell, SE simply does not support named anchors within posts. Adding it to FAQs would of course be useful, but it hardly seems worth the effort to add a custom solution just for those posts, and it's probably out of scope (and may be considered a security risk of some sort) to allow it for all posts.

#### See also: [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts)